# Laravel One To One Relationship returns all related resource from database?

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

I'm currently on an instance where a User has one Pension as the case in `Laravel` `One-To-One` relationship. With the code sample below I still wonder why it returns all associated records from the database instead of one.

User Model

```
public function pension(){
    return $this->hasOne(Pension::class)->latest();
}
```

Pension Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Then in my Pension Controller, with `App\User` imported,

```
public function user($id){

        $user = User::find($id);
        return PensionResource::collection(  
            $user->pension()->with(
                $this->particulars()
            )->get() 
        );
    }

private function particulars(){
        return [
            'user:id,surname,first_name,other_name',
            'pension_manager:id,name'
        ];
    }
```

Please **note** that I have purposefully allowed for multiple records for a user to be in the database. What could be a possible fix?

Comment: Can you elaborate on _Please note that I have purposefully allowed for multiple records for a user to be in the database_?

Comment: @vivek_23 I know if only one pension record for a user is allowed in the database, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Exactly. Laravel relationships are not meant to be in just code form, the relationship has to be respected even in terms of database rows.

Comment: I believe it's not all the time, a relationship can be `one-to-one` and `one-to-many` at the same time

Comment: How come? Any real life use case?

Comment: A user can have many job titles as his job title history and the last job title is his current job. The current job is `one-to-one` while every other related to the user on that same table is `one-to-many` which makes the user's job history.

Comment: In this case, you will need to have 3 tables namely, `user`, `job` and `job_history`. A user can have `a` job. A job can have `many` users. A user can have many job history and one job history belongs to one user. So, in your user table, you will have a job_id field which has the primary key ID of some job denoting the current job. Current job will not be stored in job_history because it's current.

Comment: Different developers have different approach to database structures. In my case, I preferred all job histories in a table where the last job title is the current job of a user. It works just fine